# Edit and Continue problems with VS 2013

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, edit-and-continue

Recently Edit and Continue with VB.net has been kinda flaky.

In one project in particular. It was working as expected the last time I touched this project.

Recently when I pause the project while the winform message pump is running, I get a message saying no code is running. When I go back to my class file (in the same project, not external) I cannot make any changes - typing does nothing in the editor.

I have another class which is part of this solution, it has no entry point but I thought I would remind VS which was the startup project. This made edit and continue seem to work. I could make changes in the code, but when I continued the old version of the code was what was actually running. It's as if I am in an external class.

I just noticed something else, when you first start the project, edit and continue seems to work fine. After you continue, if you break the code again, it stops working.

I never had edit and continue problems at all with VS2012.

VS was hanging and crashing a lot yesterday so I rebooted my computer. That did not help this problem. I also installed SP1 and that did not fix anything.

I tried compiling to X86 and Any CPU.

Is there a setting I am missing? How can I get this working?

Thanks,
Brad

Comment: Have you tried to run "clean" on your project. Sometimes the old version is having around and can't really be edited.

Comment: @Anthony. I thought I had tried that, but I did it again to be sure. No joy.

Comment: Ate you using threads?

Comment: I am not using threads in this project

Comment: I found a reference to add-ins causing similar problems. I just started VS with /safemode so they would not load. No joy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a few more things based on some suggestion in other forums.

I repaired VS, I reinstalled VS, I tried to restore my default settings. None worked. I tried a simple project to duplicate the issue that I could share to get feedback. I could not get it to not work.

So assuming then the problem was with my project and not VS I made a new project and brought over my forms, modules and classes from project with the problem. I added my references and... edit and continue now works! The only things I changed from the default project were: Target CPU: x86, and Target Framework: .Net Framework 4

I still do not know if there was some corruption or it was a bad setting. This project was originally ported from VB6 many years ago and has been through a few VS upgrades as well.